# Executing a php script with PHP

Tags: php

I have a php function to save multiple rows in database, I can't use this on the web requests since it takes much time.
In the function, first I need to obtain a list of ids from database, do some processing, then save new set data into another table.
Is it possible to run this script from php, for example from a controller?

Comment: `exec('php other_script.php')`

Comment: Why don't you just use a cronjob and run the page that takes time? Set its execution time to 0 so it won't stop...

Comment: @Thomas what's the "execution time" ?

Comment: @Dagon I think you were being sarcastic, but he means `set_time_limit()` for anyone else who wasn't aware.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: no, i really did not know what he meant and was curious, and that's not an issue with cron jobs, php cli has no default time limit

Comment: When I said execution time, I meant how long it took for the script to run. PHP is set generally to I believe 30 seconds before it stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
$output = shell_exec('php YourFile.php');
```

OR

exec

```
exec('php YourFile.php')
```

OR

cronjob ( As [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243798/thomas) mentioned )

```
* * * * * php /var/www/file.php >> /var/www/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

If you want to run it continuously [set_time_limit(0)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Problem is this will block until it finishes, better to use a cron so it doesn't block.

Comment: or just add " > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" to exec

Comment: as above you don't need to set_time_limit(0) when the script is called from cli. its 0 by defult